# How to push items into an array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I don't know what i'm not doing right be i'm finding it hard to push new variables into a scope

```
$scope.usermsg= [
  { name: 'John', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Barry', age: 43 },
  { name: 'Kim', age: 26 },
  { name: 'masa',age: '14'},
  { name: 'Fritz', age: 19 }];

  $scope.send=function(){
 $scope.varb =({"name": 'masa222',"age": '1422'})
  $scope.usermsg.push=($scope.varb)
      }
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="rows in usermsg">
<li>{{ rows.name + ' - ' + (rows.age)}}</li>
</div>


<button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-paperplane footer-btn" type="submit" ng-click="send()">
</button>
```

Comment: `$scope.usermsg.push($scope.varb)`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this

```js
// Code goes here

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

 myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
  
  $scope.usermsg= [
  { name: 'John', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Barry', age: 43 },
  { name: 'Kim', age: 26 },
  { name: 'masa',age: '14'},
  { name: 'Fritz', age: 19 }];

$scope.send = function()
{
  var item = {name:'Ajay', age : 27};
  var items = $scope.usermsg;
  items.push(item);
  return items 
}
 

  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    
    <div ng-controller= "myController">
    
    <div ng-repeat="c in usermsg">
     <div>{{c.name}}</div>
      
    </div>
    <button ng-click="send()">Click to send</button>
    
    
    </div>
    
   
  </body>
```